# How to remove a substring of characters from a PySpark Dataframe StringType() column, conditionally based on the length of strings in columns?

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark Dataframe with a StringType() column that has mostly 15 characters. However, some rows have 11 characters. Example:

```
df = 
+--------------+--------+
|             code|state|
+--------------+--------+
|'334445532234553'|wa   |
|'332452132234553'|mn   |
|'45532234553'    |fl   |
|'679645532234553'|mo   |
|'918535532234553'|ar   |
|'174925532234553'|wi   |
|'45532234553'    |al   |
|'928405532234553'|ca   |
+--------------+--------+
```

I need all rows to have 11 characters, with the last 4 characters removed from any row containing 15 characters. So this is my desired output:

```
df.show(8) = 
+-------------+-----+
|         code|state|
+-------------+-----+
|'33444553223'|wa   |
|'33245213223'|mn   |
|'45532234553'|fl   |
|'67964553223'|mo   |
|'91853553223'|ar   |
|'17492553223'|wi   |
|'45532234553'|al   |
|'92840553223'|ca   |
+-------------+-----+
```

So far I have this transformation, which removes that last 4 characters from ALL of the rows in my column called 'code':

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, col, expr

df = df.withColumn("code",expr("substring(code, 1, length(code)-4)"))
```

So I need to do something to make this conditional on the length of the string within the row.

**EDIT** With help from @gmds, I found this solution:

```
df.withColumn("code",expr("substring(code, 1, 11)"))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
df.withColumn('code', df['code'].substr(1, 11))
```

Your idea was right; it's just that you provided a changing value for the length of the substring, when you really wanted a constant.

Comment: I understand your idea of using a constant, but does this make sure that the last 4 characters are removed, as I need? How do I know it's won't remove the first 4 characters? Or, how would I adjust it if I did need to remove the first 4 characters instead of the last 4?

Comment: The second parameter of `substr` controls the length of the string. If you set it to 11, then the function will take (at most) the first 11 characters. What you're doing takes everything but the last 4 characters. As for your second question, then that would depend on whether you wanted to remove the first four characters indiscriminately, or only from those with length 15.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I try this solution, I'm getting a long error message that starts: "AnalysisException: u'Resolved attribute(s) codet#1617 missing from........"  I did double-check and the column values are definitely strings.

Comment: @TJE That's weird. Try `F.substring(F.col('code'), 1, 11)` in place of `df['code'].substr(1, 11)`?

Comment: In the end, here's what worked (a slight modification of your code): df.withColumn("code",expr("substring(code, 1, 11)"))  -- Your suggestion definitely helped me get there.

Comment: @TJE To clarify; are you saying my alternative suggestion didn't work, either? That is quite strange, to me, because I cannot reproduce the error...

Comment: yes, your alternative suggestion didn't work on my system. If it works for you, then maybe there's some discrepancy in my environment or column types. I'm new to PySpark so I'm still trying to understand it all.

Comment: That's weird. In any case, if you have an answer to your question, you should post it and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build-in length function together with substring:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length

df = df.withColumn("code", when(length(df.code) > 11, substring(df.code, 1, length(df.code) - 4)).otherwise(df.code))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question based on input from @gmds. Here it is:

```
df.withColumn("code",expr("substring(code, 1, 11)"))
```

This code sets 11 as a constant, meaning that whether the column contains a value that's 11 or 15 characters long, after the transformation they will all have the constant of 11 characters.